# What type and brand is this engineered flooring?

Tags: flooring

I bought a condo a couple of months ago. One of the first things I did was change out the floors in the one of the bedrooms. The [closest match](https://imgur.com/a/C66YfqV) I could find there these hardwood floors from [Lowes](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Style-Selections-Style-Selections-Hardwood-5-in-Gunstock-Oak-Engineered-Hardwood-Flooring-19-69-sq-ft/1000768930), but it's missing these grooves that the other floors have. I'm not sure if it's laminate, vinyl, or hardwood. On the appraisal, it just says "Resl"? The last owner left scrap planks so I've been trying to base my search off of that.

[image: old floor is on the right and new is the left]
[image: old floor is on the right and new is the left]
[image: there's some print on there]

In the first picture, the old floor is on the right and new is the left. And in the last picture, there's some print on there, so idk if they're significant to anything. Obviously, it's very hard to ask "what product is this?", but what sort of features should I sort for, instead looking at thousands of grainy images?

Comment: Pictures of the side of the planks would help. They look like engineered hardwood.